# JScript - так ли он хорош?

Tags: windows, jscript

Кто только не слышал о данном скриптовом языке, разработанном компанией мелкософта. Язык JScript и правда очень удобен: не нужно иметь особую среду разработки, никаких препроцессоров языка и т.д. Вместо всех этих обработчиков и компиляторов все делает система Windows: компилит, дебажжит( это уже во время запуска скрипта ) и, наконец, успешно запускает сам скрипт. Запуск возможен на всех версиях винды. Это стандарт( разве что в 95-ой винде не поддерживается...ну и ладно! ), к которому так долго шли девелоперы мелкософта. Все библиотеки, используемые языком поставляются в коробочке с Windows, так что можно не парится: написал однажды, работает везде. Например, вот, как легко получить базовую инфу о системе:

```
sub ReturnENV()
     set wshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     set wshProcEnv = wshShell.environment("process")

     WScript.Echo ("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: " & wshProcEnv _ 
         ("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"))
     WScript.Echo
     WScript.Echo ("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: " & wshProcEnv _
         ("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER"))
     WScript.Echo
     WScript.Echo ("OS: " & wshProcEnv ("OS"))
     WScript.Echo
     WScript.Echo ("PATH: " & wshProcEnv ("PATH"))
     WScript.Echo
     WScript.Echo ("WINDIR: " & wshProcEnv ("WINDIR"))
     WScript.Echo
end sub
```

Т.е язык, вдобавок, полностью системный!
 Это очень хорошо, не считая того, что прародитель JScript небезызвестный JavaScript! Так вот, собственно вопрос к тем, кто хоть как-то знаком с языком: **Нашли ли вы ему настояшее применение, т.е такое применение, когда он помог решить реальную задачу из жизни, а не такое, что вы им пользуетесь только на работе для заполнения табличек Excel**  =) Также хотелось бы узнать минусы данного языка.

**Благодарю!**

Comment: А где аргументы мисующего ТС'а?

Comment: Достаточно бессмысленно разговаривать об абстрактных плюсах и минусах языков, технологий, сортировок. Если есть задача, то уже можно говорить о том, как она решается с помощью `X` или `Y`. `JScript` хорош для тех целей, для которых он был задизайнен, но писать ПО для шаттлов на нем никто не будет.

Comment: Вообще то на листинге VBS, а не JScript...

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, как ни странно, но это абсолютно всем известно, кто хотя бы разок "прикасался" к JScript. В данный момент интересно получить ответ на последний абзац вопроса...

Comment: @Dexter Ну, может быть, здесь и найдется эксперт по `JScript`. Мой опыт общения с данным языком заканчивается на написании `bash-`подобных скриптов, поэтому ничего конкретного сказать не смогу :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, ну это не удивительно. Язык ведь и правда создан для программирования автоматизированных действий в офисных программах, это потом он уже перерос во что-то большее. На данном форуме нет даже ни одной записи с тегом "JScript". **В любом случае спасибо!**

Comment: ИМХО, майкрософт в этом плане(автоматизированных действий) делает ставку на PowerShell

Comment: Ну и у JScript`а есть будущее, имхо! Язык объектный, системный, а значит можно его считать полноценным. Не знаю правда, почему он не популяризован?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень удобный ЯП из "коробки" в составе ОС. Изучаю около года и могу сказать, что его:

Плюсы:

- Прост в изучении, удобный синтаксис, в отличии от powershell или vbs.
- Код можно переносить с минимальными затратами времени на VBS, .Net платформу.

Минусы:

- Отсутствие справки. Каждый раз лазить на msdn не удобно. Поэтому лучше всего скачать [script56.chm](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2764).

В совокупности с [WMI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WMI), программы на JScript выходят на новый уровень.

В повседневной жизни использую для разных целей. Изучаю "регулярки", написал интерпритатор простенький, в консоле Windows удобно писать регулярку и тут же получать результат. В интернете есть мой GUI для работы с g2mtranscoder. Первую версию писал, когда только начанал изучать язык. Вторую версию, полностью переписанную с нуля, всё никак не могу закончить. Постоянно какие-нибудь мелочи устраняю/оптимизирую. На работе использую для разных целей. Из последнего - написал скрипт, который проверяет на наличие winlocker`а в системе.

Comment: Вот спасибо! Много полезной инфы рассказали вы мне. Плюс и галочка =)

---
Как основной язык, JScript у меня никода не будет, т.к слишком он стремный что ли =) Но для кодинга на "чистых виндах" без всяких сред программирования и компиляторов буду применять только его! Здесь мелкософтники не просчитались - пакетный язык - это огромный плюс!

Comment: Забыл добавить, что продолжением JScript является - JScript .Net. Компилируемый, строго типизированный ЯП.

Comment: @evlanoff, ерунду пишете

> строго типизированный 

Никогда таким не был.

Answer (score 2):

<small>Опять в коммент не влезло.</small>

Непонятно, о чем этот вопрос. И в тексте вопроса и в ответе путается VBScript и JScript. Последний пошел (точнее поехал на велосипеде) не от MS Office, а от JavaScript браузера. А имя такое стало из-за давнего конфликта с Sun касательно Java.
Поскольку Microsoft любят всё модульное, то и появилась отдельная среда исполнения VBScript, предназначенная для логон-скриптов и прочих задач сисадминов. Обратите внимание на регистр идентификаторов в WSH и увидите, что именно VBScript был первичен, а микрософтовская реализация JS туда пошла прицепом из-за той же модульности. И как уже отметили, генеральная линия MS направлена PowerShell c CLR.

Comment: @evlanoff, не подскажите новую ссылку для скачивания справки по jscript и желательно на русском: я очень интересуюсь этим языком, а полный мануал по языку не могу найти. Вашу ссылку увидел - обрадовался, но... она устарела.. В Инете попадается, но, мне кажется, там везде описана лишь крошечная часть языка.

Comment: Справка по JScript: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1271184/244950

Answer (score 0):

JScript исполняет свою часть работы, и то что о умеет на отлично. Для новичков именно его, я посоветовал бы изучить для начала, что-бы прощупать так сказать внутренности windows, вместе с написанием батников т.е. *.bat и *.cmd. Потом уже пробовать *.vbs.
У Microsoft найти какую либо документацию это боль и страдание...
Поэтому друзья, оставляю вам здесь ᚜ ↧ ᚛ последнюю найденную мной ссылку, на этот чудо язык:
0. [Документация по JScript](http://ru-jscript.com/jstoc.htm)

1. [Документация по JScript](https://documentation.help/MS-Office-JScript/sgWorkingWithDrives.htm)

P.S. И еще один совет для новичков, чем раньше тем лучше подружится с Autohotkey. Тогда вам удастся подчинить себе в Windows все, a при особой сноровке даже Chrome. Ну а если хотите попробовать Баш т.е. Bash прямо в Windows. Скачайте и установите Гитару т.е. Git...